How to split column value into rows in db2 sql?
value in column like
id    val
112   Apple[AP1,APB1], Mango[MG3], Pear[TXV1]
123   Pie[PP1], Guacamole[GUA12,GUA90,GUA99]

And result should be
id    val
112   Apple[AP1,APB1]
112   Mango[MG3]
112   Pear[TXV1]
123   Pie[PP1]
123   Guacamole[GUA12,GUA90,GUA99]

I tried using comma as the split sign, but it wont work when there several items inside "[ ]".

CSV or other structed data in a column is a broken schema in the first place. Even the result you want is not good for a database.

@JoelCoehoorn Thanks for sharing your ideas! Actually I need to count the individual value under unique id in the following steps and i find my description was wrong :O

Please edit the question if the description is wrong. I got this far with a possible solution  https://dbfiddle.uk/namMwKcX  but DB2 stopped responding, and if the question needs to change, the solution probably will also.

The question is not fit for a relational database. You are trying to do imperative programming in the database, and it would be a lot easier to implement this logic in the programming language of your preference instead of SQL.

Try This..
WITH RECURSIVE SplitCTE (id, original_val, val, rest) AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        val AS original_val,
        SUBSTR(val, 1, LOCATE(']', val)) AS val,
        CASE
            
            WHEN LOCATE('], ', val) > 0 THEN SUBSTR(val, LOCATE('], ', val) + 3)
            ELSE ''
        END AS rest
    FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
        id,
        original_val,
        SUBSTR(rest, 1, LOCATE(']', rest)) AS val,
        CASE
            WHEN LOCATE('], ', rest) > 0 THEN SUBSTR(rest, LOCATE('], ', rest) + 3)
            ELSE ''
        END AS rest
    FROM SplitCTE
    WHERE rest <> ''
)
SELECT id, TRIM(val) AS val
FROM SplitCTE
ORDER BY id;


In this case, you can use XMLTABLE, just use tokenization to separate ', ' values in the columns.
Please get the code below and dbfiddle link.

WITH main (id, val) as
    (values 
        (112, 'Apple[AP1,APB1], Mango[MG3], Pear[TXV1]')
      , (123, 'Pie[PP1], Guacamole[GUA12,GUA90,GUA99]')
    )
    
SELECT m.id,tok AS result FROM main AS m
,xmltable
    (
        'for $id in tokenize($s, ", ") return <i>{string($id)}</i>'
        PASSING
            m.val as "s"
        columns
            seq for ORDINALITY,
            tok varchar(125) PATH '.'
    ) as c1


----Result

#|ID |RESULT                      |
-+---+----------------------------+
1|112|Apple[AP1,APB1]             |
2|112|Mango[MG3]                  |
3|112|Pear[TXV1]                  |
4|123|Pie[PP1]                    |
5|123|Guacamole[GUA12,GUA90,GUA99]|



suggestion: Please use (semicolon) ';' instead of (comma) ','. This is better for your safe data. For example
Apple[AP1,APB1]; Mango[MG3]; Pear[TXV1]
